# Getting BAD ACCESS error when trying to insert an int into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this method here that turns integer inputs from two UITextFields into binary code:

```
//assume anything that isn't allocated here has been taken care of in the header file
-(IBAction)valuesChanged
{
    while ((![input1.text isEqualToString:@""]) && (![input2.text isEqualToString:@""]))
    {
        if (bitRange.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {flowLimit = 8;}
        else if (bitRange.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {flowLimit = 16;}
        else {flowLimit = 32;}

        NSMutableArray* bin1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:32];
        NSMutableArray* bin2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:32];
        NSMutableArray* resBin = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:32];

        input1Decimal = [input1.text intValue];
        input2Decimal = [input2.text intValue];

    int decimalDummy = input1Decimal;
    while (decimalDummy > 0) 
    {
        if (decimalDummy == 1) 
        {
            [bin1 addObject:1];
            decimalDummy--;
        }
        else 
        {
            [bin1 addObject:(decimalDummy % 2)]; //this is where I get the error
            decimalDummy = decimalDummy/2;
        }
    }

    decimalDummy = input2Decimal;
    while (decimalDummy > 0) 
    {
        if (decimalDummy == 1) 
        {
            [bin2 addObject:1];
            decimalDummy--;
        }
        else 
        {
            [bin2 addObject:(decimalDummy % 2)];
            decimalDummy = decimalDummy/2;
        }
    }

    while ([bin1 count] < flowLimit) {[bin1 addObject:0];}
    while ([bin2 count] < flowLimit) {[bin2 addObject:0];}

    NSString* string1 = @"";
    NSString* string2 = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < flowLimit; i++) 
    {
        string1 = [[bin1 objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:string1];
        string2 = [[bin2 objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:string2];
    }
    [output1 setText:string1];
    [output2 setText:string2];

    [bin1 release];
    [bin2 release];
    [resBin release];
}
}
```

I labeled the spot where I'm getting a bad access error. Anyone know why it's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure! You have to put objects in `NSArray`s. Plain `int`s aren't objects, they're primitive types. You can wrap them in `NSNumber`s if you want to put them in an `NSArray`:

```
NSNumber *wrappedInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(decimalDummy % 2)];
[array addObject:wrappedInt];
```